# using DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, directoryservices

I've got a new environment and I'm trying to rebuild web page.

I got an error that

> the namespace DirectoryService is missing.

However, I've made the following declarations:

1. Within the .cs file:
   `using System.DirectoryServices;`
2. Within the Web.config:
   `add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/`
   I skip the brackets in front and at the end, due to the fact that the code was not published!
3. And I also add the reference in the project (`System.DirectoryServices`).

What I recorgnize is that I've got a pick on e.g. `System.Data` within the references but do not get a pick on `System.DirectoryServices`.

Any idea?

P.S.: I'm using VS2013

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Found the answer: The GAC was looking for .NET Framework 4.0 and installed is 4.5. 
Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: The GAC was looking for .NET Framework 4.0 and installed is 4.5.

Thanks a lot! Cheers